# Math operators in .sg file of Shogun meta example

Tags: shogun

The Shogun toolbox saves its meta examples in .sg files written in a meta-language, as described in the docs. Can you provide any resources on the syntax of this meta-language? I suspect that the necessary information lies in the "parse.py" and "translate.py" files under "examples/meta/generator", but that doesn't help with my particular problem, math operators.

What would the correct syntax of the following line be?

```
bool result = ((5/2) > 3)
```

Make currently complains about `/` and `>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are examples for basic meta language usage in `examples/meta/src/meta_api/*.sg`.

The meta language currently does not support basic math operators. This is in fact on purpose as the listings are just supposed to be used to illustrate Shogun's API usage.